# Delete a specific item from listview and shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, selecteditem

I am trying to delete a specific item from listView and from sharedPreferences on long item click.

```
    ApplicationData.java
         public static void remove(Context context,String dtl){
                SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, 0);
                sp.edit().remove(dtl).commit();
                ApplicationData.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

It says:

> Error:(53, 32) error: method remove in class ApplicationData cannot be
>   applied to given types; required: Context,String found: ,String reason: actual argument  cannot be converted to Context by method
>   invocation conversion

Comment: Can you post your Activity/fragment class?, the one in which you implemented your `onItemLongClick`

Comment: @zozelfelfo jus posted it. now with Fahim suggestion it doesn't show error but neither deletes item

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext() instead of this

```
ApplicationData.remove(this, dtl.toString());
```

Use this

```
ApplicationData.remove(getBaseContext(), dtl.toString());
```

Comment: doesn't shows error, but the item is not deleted. long item clicked doesn't nothing

Comment: Here sp.edit().remove(dtl).commit(); you are passing the object in the remove() method. You need to pass the keyname to remove it from shared preference.

Comment: what do you mean with key name? I am passing the name of item

Comment: you are passing  RESTEndpoint dtl = ApplicationData.RESTEndpoints.get(position);        You are passing RestEndPoint object in the remove method   sp.edit().remove(dtl).commit();

Comment: I am converting it to String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72403/discussion-between-arual-and-fahim).